# Retrieve multiple contacts from contactList in android

Tags: android

I want to select multiple contacts directly from contact list , without saving the complete contacts list in listView with checkbox and then selecting. 
On button click,phone's contact list should open and user can select multiple contacts from there and selected contacts will be stored in an arrayList.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to write your own ListView to do so.

Comment: Aashish- is it not possible without creating a ListView ??

Comment: I had tried long ago. I couldn't find a way except ListView.